# The remove button and the readURL in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple input files which are generated by javascript. When I click a button to add an input file, it will create a new input file.

This is the script for that:

```
<input type="file" class="address" id="address0"/>
<button type="button" class="addmore">Add More Picture</button>

var rowNum = 0;

$("body").on("click", ".addmore", function() {
    rowNum++;
    var $address = $('.address').last();
    var nextHtml = $address.clone();
    nextHtml.attr('id', 'address' + rowNum);
    var hasRmBtn = $('.rmbtn', nextHtml).length > 0;
      if (!hasRmBtn) 
        {
          var rm = "<button type='button' class='rmbtn'>Remove</button>"
          $('.removebtn', nextHtml).append(rm);
        }
    $address.after(nextHtml); 
});

$("body").on("click", ".rmbtn", function() {
    $(this).parents('.addresses').remove();
});
```

The code for adding new input file is working fine. However, the function for adding the remove button doesn't work. It doesn't create a remove button.

```
          var rm = "<button type='button' class='rmbtn'>Remove</button>"
          $('.removebtn', nextHtml).append(rm);
```

In which in the code above I want to add a remove button for each input file.

And also, I have a script for reading the file. So when I browse a file of an image, it will show up the image.

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#address0").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
```

However it only shows up the first image.

Here is the full fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/Klaudia/a652du55/

Please help and Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you are doing, the code for adding the remove button needs to be a bit different. Something like:

```
  var $address = $('.address').last();
  var nextHtml = $address.clone();
  nextHtml.attr('id', 'address' + rowNum);
  $address.after(nextHtml); 
  if (nextHtml.find('.rmbtn').length == 0) {
      $("<button type='button' class='rmbtn'>Remove</button>").insertAfter(nextHtml);
  }
```

Since $address in your Fiddle is an input, I did not understand how it could ever have a child with class 'rmbtn', but I left that test in anyway under the assumption that maybe in production $address might be something more complex.

The process is: After you add nextHtml to the DOM (after $address), check if it has a remove button. If not, create the remove button and insert it after nextHtml. If $address was something other than an input, you could append to it instead.

See [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bobdye/wepxhdoe/), which is a variation of yours.

Comment: Hi, bobdye, thanks. but the remove button doesn't remove the image.